# Is there a way of specifying a selector without the @selector syntax / what is going on behind the scenes with @selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, runtime, selector

Is `@selector` a convenience syntax for some sort of longer C syntax, or is it a "hard wired" part of the Objective-C language/compiler? For example, I know that when I call `@property`, depending on the arguments, different equivalent Objective-C code is "generated" re: getters and setters. What is going on behind the scenes with `@selector`? Is it specifying an Objective-C message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@selector()` is a part of the language. It specifies literal `SEL` just like `@""` specifies a literal `NSString`.

It's worth understanding that `@selector` represents a selector, not a message. A selector is just a name. It's just one small part of a message. It doesn't even carry type information.

Also note that `@property` doesn't generate anything. It just promises that the object will respond to one or two selectors (the getter and the setter). There are several ways to fulfill that contract. `@synthesize` is just one of them. You can also manually implement the needed methods, or use `@dynamic` to promise that it will somehow be handled at runtime.

Comment: So, roughly, `@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)` is about the same as `(SEL *)popViewControllerAnimated:` ?

Comment: It's just `SEL`, not `SEL*`, but this would be basically true if the latter were legal syntax. It's kind of like saying that `@"foo"` is the same as `(NSString *)foo`. For a rough enough version of true, that's true.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title, `NSSelectorFromString` will let you create a selector from an `NSString` (you can also do the opposite with `NSStringFromSelector`), although it's more efficient to use `@selector`.

Comment: Specifically, `@selector` directives are turned into SELs at compile time, while `NSSelectorFromString()` is a normal function that is called at runtime.